# How to wait for the function to execute before returning the variable

Tags: swift, synchronization

I found that inside the observeSingleEvent brackets, the track has successfully obtained data, but outside the observeSingleEvent brackets, the track does not actually store the data.
**I use iOS 16.4 and Xcode 14.3**

I tried Completion and await, but I'm not sure whether it's because of the update or my programming error, so the problem has not been solved.

My code:

```
func getTrack(userID: String) -> Bool
{
    let reference=Database.database().reference().child("User").child(userID).child("Track")
    var track: Bool?
    
    reference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value)
    {snapshot in
        if let data=snapshot.value as? Bool
        {
            track=data
        }
        //Gets data successfully
        print("Inside: \(track)")
    }
    //nil
    print("Outside: \(track)")
    return track ?? false
}
```